# Joomla registration override

Tags: joomla, components, overriding

I would like to override my joomla registration component in the way to have next to it the login form as well. As first step I made in my template folder the registration call but from here I don't know how to include the login form.

thanks
fefe

Answer (score 0):

Is this roughly the idea you're looking for?

http://zebiangroup.markmurphy.ca/component/users/?view=login

If so, I'll be packaging it up as an extension shortly. If you need it asap leave me a message at markmurphy.ca and I'll get in touch.

I'll be back to update this post when I have the extension finished and uploaded.

[Edit:]

I'd hate to leave you totally in the dark and keep you searching for an answer so I'll point you in the right direction.

I was able to write a system plug-in that overrides the user components' controller.php only if that component was the one being requested and if the requested view was for the login or registration and if the task was only to display.

From there I had the new controller.php override the requested view name substituting my own and adding the appropriate models, references and variables to the view.

After that all I had to do was add the layout to my active themes "html" folder under com_users.

Comment: yes this I would like to achive. I have been making it as well but is having still handicaps.